# Bubble sort swap method clarification

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

Ive been following a course that goes over bubble sort but one part of the swap method implementation has been bothering me. The part that doesnt make sense to me and hoping someone can clarify has to do with the comparison regarding the index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = {20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22};

       //start at index 6 which is -22 value; as long as the length of the array is more than 0; decrement down to the first index
        for (int lastUnsortedIndex = intArray.length -1; lastUnsortedIndex > 0; lastUnsortedIndex -- ){

           //i=0; as long as i is less than length of intArray -1, so 6; i++
            for(int i =0; i< lastUnsortedIndex; i++){
                //if value at index i is more than value at index i+1
                if(intArray[i] > intArray[i +1]){
                    //swap their positions
                    swap(intArray, i , i+1);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int num : intArray){
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
    //for swapping
    public static void swap (int[] array , int i , int j){
        System.out.println("i= "+i);
        System.out.println("j= "+j);

        if(i == j){ // if they are the same then just return
            return;
        }
        int temp = array[i];// need the temporary variable to hold value at position i because
        //... we are going to swap array[i] with j, but still need to retain the value so we can assign it to array[j]
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;

    }
```

As you can see  **if(i == j){return;}** seems to only be comparing the index if im not mistaken. Why even bother doing this check? Doesnt seem like i will ever equal i+1, unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: `Why even bother doing this check?` It's a small optimization.    If i == j, then it's the same object and obviously  no need to swap.

Comment: when `i==j` is true then obviously `array[i] == array[j]` is true as well. Then no need to write to memory to exchange object with itself.

Comment: Efficiency.  The if check is cheap whereas doing the swap of itself is relatively expensive.

Comment: Although I'd question whether it's truly "efficient."  The swap itself is only swapping two integers (Java doesn't have a copy constructor and doesn't ever copy heap memory, unless you work pretty hard at it).  So doing a comparison and branch might actually make the code slower.

Comment: How can i ever be equal to j? J is set to be i +1

Comment: Fair point, I think you are right about that. @JessicaJones

Comment: The only reason I'm even asking about this is that the person who wrote it is an expert in her field. Surely there is a good reason for this?

Comment: This is called [**defensive programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), which is to code for and/or guard against conditions that may not happen today, but might happen in the future, as someone (yourself or other) modifies the code. You are correct that the method is currently only called with values that are different, but that might change, so coding for it now makes the code more *robust*, i.e. less likely to misbehave if things change. --- It is more likely to happen if you copy/reuse the method in some other code, where it can happen.

Comment: @Andreas I've seen a lot of implementations of bubble sort that use a swap method. This is the first time I've seen anyone do something like this.

Comment: I'm not sure that "defensive programming" even applies here though.  Even if the swap routine gets called with two identical arguments, nothing bad will happen, and the "defensive" code arguably makes the method worse.  This feels like perhaps an "expert" copied code from another language without thinking much about it.

Comment: @JessicaJones You are correct. The check for `i==j` is unnecessary in the code you've posted, because a bubble sort will never attempt to swap an element with itself. An example of an algorithm that might is a Fisher-Yates shuffle. So if that's just a generic reusable `swap` function that your expert uses for everything, then it's sort of understandable. But as [markspace already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099377/bubble-sort-swap-method-clarification#comment118604205_67099377), it probably makes the code slower, even for code where `i` and `j` might be equal.

Comment: @JessicaJones You are correct.  It isn't needed  here.  But if you were writing a public utility swap method it would be a good thing to have to avoid unnecessary swaps should `i == j`  And sometimes, even experts make mistakes.  I have seen Objects in the API code that are completely unused.  Probably left as an after thought.

Comment: @WJS YAGNI, Jessica Jones is right, this does not make sense here

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to do the check. It's also pointless to pass `i+1` to `swap`. Just pass `i`, and replace `j` with `i+1` everywhere. Don't worry about checking for equality. Remove the print statements if you care about speed.